# Highlight a single point with a marker in lineplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot

I would like to highlithgt a single point on my lineplot graph using a marker. So far I managed to create my plot and insert the highlight where I wanted.

The problem is that I have 4 differents lineplot (4 different categorical attributes) and I get the marker placed on every sigle lineplot like in the following image:

[image: Plot]

I would like to place the marker only on the 2020 line (the purple one). This is my code so far:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
gs0 = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2, figure=fig, hspace=0.2)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[0,:]) # lineplot
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1,0]) #Used for another plot not shown here
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1,1]) #Used for another plot not shown here

flatui = ["#636EFA", "#EF553B", "#00CC96", "#AB63FA"]

sns.lineplot(ax=ax1,x="number of weeks", y="avg streams", hue="year", data=df, palette=flatui, marker = 'o', markersize=20, fillstyle='none', markeredgewidth=1.5, markeredgecolor='black', markevery=[5])

ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{:,.0f}'.format(x/1000) + 'K'))

ax1.set(title='Streams trend')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2))
```

I used the `markevery` field to place a marker in position 5. Is there a way to specify also on which line/category place my marker?

**EDIT**: This is my dataframe:

```
    avg streams date    year    number of weeks
0   145502.475  01-06   2017    0
1   158424.445  01-13   2017    1
2   166912.255  01-20   2017    2
3   169132.215  01-27   2017    3
4   181889.905  02-03   2017    4
... ... ... ... ...
181 760505.945  06-26   2020    25
182 713891.695  07-03   2020    26
183 700764.875  07-10   2020    27
184 753817.945  07-17   2020    28
185 717685.125  07-24   2020    29

186 rows × 4 columns
```

Comment: just do a `ax1.scatter([5]*df.shape[1], df.loc[5])`?

Comment: Unrelated but you use `plot = sns.lineplot(...)` when in reality `plot == ax1` does not need to be saved.

Comment: @Guimoute Fixed, it was "spurious" code derived from copy-paste.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @wwii Edited and inserted Dataframe as code snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`markevery` is a [Line2D](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html) property. `sns.lineplot` doesn't return the lines so you need to get the line you want to *annotate* from [the Axes](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/axes_api.html). Remove all the marker parameters from the lineplot call and add ...

```
lines = ax1.get_lines()
```

If the 2020 line/data is the fourth in the series,

```
line = lines[3]
line.set_marker('o')
line.set_markersize(20)
line.set_markevery([5])
line.set_fillstyle('none')
line.set_markeredgewidth(1.5)
line.set_markeredgecolor('black')

# or
props = {'marker':'o','markersize':20, 'fillstyle':'none','markeredgewidth':1.5,
         'markeredgecolor':'black','markevery': [5]}
line.set(**props)
```

---

Another option, inspired by Quang Hoang's comment would be to *add* a circle around/at the point deriving the point from the DataFrame.

```
x = 5    # your spec
wk = df['number of weeks']==5
yr = df['year']==2020
s = df[wk & yr]
y = s['avg streams'].to_numpy()
# or 
y = df.loc[(df['year']==2020) & (df['number of weeks']==5),'avg streams'].to_numpy()

ax1.plot(x,y, 'ko', markersize=20, fillstyle='none', markeredgewidth=1.5)
```